# NameError: name 'storage' is not defined python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to set up a dataflow job for converting a json file to csv and write it to a bucket using python script below for writing to bucket. ( i tried this in pyenv virtualenv 3.8.13) as i am using apache-beam. i tried changing many versions of python and google-cloud-storage. is there any alternative to it without using storage library ?

```
import apache_beam as beam
import pandas as pd
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from google.cloud import storage
from smart_open import openclass WriteCSVFile(beam.DoFn):

def __init__(self, bucket_name):
    self.bucket_name = bucket_name

def start_bundle(self):
    self.client = storage.Client()
    

def process(self, mylist):
    df = pd.DataFrame(mylist, columns={'account_id': str, 'isActive': str, 'balance': str, 'age': str, 'eyeColor': str, 'name': str, 'gender': str, 'company': str, 'email': str, 'phone': str, 'address':str})
    bucket = self.client.get_bucket(self.bucket_name)
    bucket.blob(f"output_poc4.csv").upload_from_string(df.to_csv(index=False), 'text/csv')
```

below is the error log

```
File "/home/myprject/dataflow_poc.py", line 86, in <module>
run()
 File "/home/myprject/dataflow_poc.py", line 79, in run
(pipeline | 'Start' >> beam.Create([None])
File "/home/myprject/.pyenv/versions/dataflow/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 598, in __exit__
self.result.wait_until_finish()
File "/home/myprject/.pyenv/versions/dataflow/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 1673, in wait_until_finish
raise DataflowRuntimeException(
  apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline 
failed. State: FAILED, Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1458, in 
apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 553, in 

  apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_start_bundle
  File 
 "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 559, in 

 apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker 
  .invoke_start_bundle
  File 
 "/home/myprject/dataflow_poc.py", 
  line 53, in start_bundle
 NameError: name 'storage' is not 
 defined
```

below is my few packages from my pip freeze

```
apache-beam==2.40.0
bcrypt==3.2.2
cachetools==4.2.4
certifi==2022.6.15
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.0
cloudpickle==2.1.0
crcmod==1.7
cryptography==37.0.2
dill==0.3.1.1


  google-api-core==1.31.6
  google-apitools==0.5.31
  google-auth==1.35.0
  google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
  google-cloud==0.34.0
  google-cloud-bigquery==2.34.4
  google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.13.2
  google-cloud-bigtable==1.7.2
  google-cloud-core==1.7.2
  google-cloud-datastore==1.15.5
  google-cloud-dlp==3.7.1
  google-cloud-language==1.3.2
  google-cloud-pubsub==2.13.0
  google-cloud-pubsublite==1.4.2
  google-cloud-recommendations-ai==0.2.0
  google-cloud-spanner==1.19.3
  google-cloud-storage==2.4.0
  google-cloud-videointelligence==1.16.3
  google-cloud-vision==1.0.2
  google-crc32c==1.3.0
  google-resumable-media==2.3.3
  googleapis-common-protos==1.56.3
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your `from google.cloud import storage` inside your `start_bundle` function?

Comment: thanks a lot .. this seems to be working..  now i am not able to read files in bucket althogh they are in correct location.No such file or directory: 'gs://poc-test-bucket-gcp-test/input/input_poc.json' [while running 'Read JSON-ptransform-27']..  inspite importing from google.cloud import storage explicitely any idea ?

Comment: Regarding your new error, you may try to double check your bucket URI and also the exact file name if it exists on your defined path. Nonetheless, you may post it as a new question with the exact error message and with your code as well (ensuring that your file really exists in the path). I posted my comment as answer with additional reference for future use of the community that may encounter the same use case. You may upvote/accept it if you find my answer helpful so that others may know that you've been sufficiently helped on this specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to move the `from google.cloud import storage` inside the function where you used import. In your case, it must be inside the `start_bundle` function.

You may refer to this [handling of NameError](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how_do_i_handle_nameerrors) documentation which also mentioned that

> By default, global imports, functions, and variables defined in the main session are not saved during the serialization of a Dataflow job.

Answer (score 0):

add from google.cloud import storage inside the definition of start_bundle